# Android Studio not recognising changes made in imported project library module

Tags: java, android, module, libraries, zxing

I have downloaded ZXing core source files, and created a new project with these source files. I then imported this project as a new module into my main project.

This has worked fine, and it all compiles and runs smoothly.

However when I try and change some of the code in the imported project, such as create a new method, the IDE doesn't detect any errors on compiling, but when I run the application, it says no such method exists.

[Here is a screenshot of the error I get when I tried adding and calling a method called please() within the imported project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtSzG.jpg)

[Here is a screenshot of the actual method I added to the imported project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEFYS.jpg)

I called this in my main application as follows:

```
Log.i(TAG, "" + Decoder.please());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? Also closing the Android Studio and re-opening?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding did it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? Also closing the Android Studio and re-opening?

Just answering so OP can choose the best answer and close the question